# Thunderbird profile folder gone

Tags: windows, email, thunderbird

I posted yesterday about losing my Thunderbird profile. I'm trying to figure out what happened, and would like your help.

The "Profiles" folder has vanished from C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird. All of my email seems to have disappeared. I tried running Recuva and while it finds other deleted files in AppData, it does not show anything for Thunderbird. Everything else on my computer is working normally.

The only thing I can think of was that chkdsk did detect (and possibly correct) a bad block on the hard drive. Is it possible that the Profiles folder was in that bad block?

Do you have any suggestions for how I can attempt to determine what happened to the folder?

Comment: If you are running Windows 7 then you should be able to right-click on the `C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird` folder (if that is where thunderbird is indeed storing the profile) and then select `Restore previous versions` which should allow you to restore the missing data.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no previous versions available. Any idea why the folder would just disappear?

Comment: Pity, as that is by far the easiest way to get data back.  It could be that in repairing your disk `chkdsk` invalidated your shadow copy at the same time, unless you yourself have disabled the System Restore feature.

Comment: System Restore isn't disabled. What would cause a folder to disappear like that?

Comment: Do you have the link  to your previous question by chance? It seems you've lost your cookie for the account you posted this with?

Comment: It's too late to help you right now, but I suggest you start backing up your Thunderbird profiles folder. You can do this manually, with some disk back-up software, or by using a specialized backup programs like [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/).